# RibbonComboBox how to do "on text changed event"

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ribbon, ribbon-control

I want to get the value that is typed in the ribbon combobox to filter my listview but it doesn't have a "on text changed event" and if i use the KeyUp/Down event or PreviewTextIntput it resets the value of the combobox

And if i try it like below the `combobox.text` gets the right value but the selection begins in the beginning of the combobox.

```
private _name as String

Private Sub cboName_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles cboName.KeyUp
cboName.Text = _name
End Sub

Private Sub cboName_PreviewTextInput(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs) Handles cboName.PreviewTextInput
_name += e.Text
End Sub
```

using a  ribbonComboBox - from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx
download link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11877

Comment: which ribbon control are you using?

Comment: a ribbonComboBox - from Microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use binding with the *UpdateSourceTrigger* set to **ProperyChanged** on the Text property of the ComboBox:

```
Text="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

In this way, each time text is added or removed the binded property value will be changed.So you could do whatever you want each time the text is changed. Similar to "on text changed" event that you're looking after.

Comment: The problem now is when i fill in "t", the autocomplete adds the first name that starts with an "t" like "tom" and if i filter, it filters on "tom" and not on "t"